# Browsers does not plays my mp4 (H.264) file with <video> tag

Tags: html, html5-video, h.264, codec, mpeg-4

I embedded my own mp4 (H.264) file onto HTML5 file using *<video>* tag.

But browsers does not play the video.

The browsers which I tried are *Firefox* and *Chrome*. Neither seem to not play the video (video is loaded,  but the screen is still black and the seek bar does not move from 0:00).
Other videos such as Youtube  tag is successfully played.

Is this caused by some codec issues?

The codec is *H.264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part10) (avc1)*.

Does anyone have some advises?

Comment: Did you try Safari? Firefox will certainly not play MP4, chrome should though... for now...

Comment: you can edit your question and add some code, will be nice.